# Term::TermKey: What is the right way to catch mouseevents and keypresses?

Tags: perl, terminal, mouseevent, libtermkey

This works for the key-presses but not for mouse-clicks. What should I change here to make it work ([Term::TermKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aTermKey))?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
use utf8;
use Term::TermKey qw(FLAG_UTF8);
my $tk = Term::TermKey->new( \*STDIN );
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)' if $tk->get_flags & FLAG_UTF8;

while( 1 ) {
    my $key;
    $tk->waitkey( $key );

    if ( $key->type_is_mouse ) {
        my ( $ev, $button, $line, $col ) = $tk->interpret_mouse( $key );
        say "event : $ev";
        say "button: $button";
        say "line  : $line";
        say "col   : $col";
    }
    else {
        say "<", $tk->format_key( $key, 0 ), ">";
    }
}
```

Comment: binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)' if $tk->get_flags & FLAG_UTF8;
You likely mean `encoding(UTF-8)` here

Comment: I thought they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I activate the mouse-mode it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
use utf8;
use Term::TermKey qw(FLAG_UTF8);
my $tk = Term::TermKey->new( \*STDIN );
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)' if $tk->get_flags & FLAG_UTF8;

$|++;

print "\e[?1003h";

say "Quit with \"q\"";
while( 1 ) {
    my $key;
    $tk->waitkey( $key );

    if ( $key->type_is_mouse ) {
        my ( $ev, $button, $line, $col ) = $tk->interpret_mouse( $key );
        say "event : $ev";
        say "button: $button";
        say "line  : $line";
        say "col   : $col";
    }
    else {
        say "<", $tk->format_key( $key, 0 ), ">";
        last if $tk->format_key( $key, 0 ) eq 'q';
    }
}

print "\e[?1003l";
```

Comment: That's the one. `libtermkey` can recognise mouse events if it receives them, but since it doesn't talk to the terminal initially, it can't enable mouse mode. Your of DEC mode 1003 is sufficient for that.